# GitLab CI/CD copy file from remote repo

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab-ci

there is a repo where located ***template.yml*** and ***overwritePom.sh*** the tree looks like this:

- templateProject

  - template.yml
  - overwritePom.sh

**template.yml**

```yaml
test:
  stage: build
  image: $NEXUS_DOCKER_HUB_PROXY_URL/openjdk:11-jdk
  script:
    - ./mvnw clean verify
  after_script:
    - ./overwritePom.sh
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1h
    paths:
      - target/
```

in another porject I would like to include this yml in gitlab-ci.yml

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'project/templateProject'
    ref: master
    file: '/template.yml'
```

but I'm getting error that ***"./overwritePom.sh: No such file or directory"***

I need somehow to copy the bash script into the project where I'm calling template.yml, but not sure how to do it properly ?